# angular filter not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

**[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/5711/)**

In the below code its working for both filters. For example if I give

`<li ng-repeat="list in arr | filter:DegreeName='masters'">`

or

`<li ng-repeat="list in arr | filter:DegreeName='certificate'">`

I get the result which is not expected. May be some silly mistake but I am not able to figure out.

**html**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <li ng-repeat="list in arr | filter:DegreeName='masters'">
    {{list.Name}}-{{list.DegreeName}} - {{list.DegreeCode}}{{list.URL}}
    </li>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
alert();
    $scope.arr = [{"URL":"/online-degrees/certificate-nursing-education","NavKey":"certificate-nursing-education","Name":"Nursing Education","AOS":"Nursing","DegreeName":"certificate","DegreeCode":"CERT","LearningFormat":"Structured","DegreeTitle":"Post-Masters Certificate"}];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be specifying data to be match in JSON format.

```
<li ng-repeat="list in arr | filter: {DegreeName: 'masters'}">
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/5712/)

---

You could pass equality check value to `true`, if you want to filter those many value which are exactly matching with text. But as I can see the 1st part of the solution would be appropriate for your scenario.

```
<li ng-repeat="list in arr | filter: {DegreeName: 'masters'}: true">
```

Comment: Thanks but what was the issue and why was it working randomly

Comment: its breaking when I am using multiple filters like on is custom filter example
`list in doctorallist = (arr | programListingFilter:map | filter:{DegreeName='doctoral'})`

here `programListingFilter:map ` return some list from that I need to filter by doctoral

Comment: What is `programListingFilter:map`

Comment: check my code i added. map is array of indices `[0,2,3,2]` etc

Comment: @SusheelSingh could you help me to reproduce issue [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/5715/)

Comment: sorry ignore it was some other issue I fixed. Thanks for heads up.